# Git Merge from Unmanaged Project

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, dvcs

If I downloaded a sample project (not Git managed) on a website and I created a branch and some commits to this project. Then, the original author made some updates to this project and published on the website...

Now how can I merge this update (not Git managed) to my Git managed project??

I am new user of VCS/Git.

Thanks.
Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a second branch that starts at the original SHA you started from (before you made any changes).

Check out that branch.

Replace the contents of the working directory with the new version of the outside code.

`git add .` and `git add -u` to stage all of the changes and removals.

Commit.

Check out your original branch, and merge the second branch in.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I just use "Copy and Paste" to replace the files and folders?  How about if the author renamed or removed some files/folders??

Comment: You should clear out the contents of the working directory and then copy in the new version. That way renames and removals will all get picked up properly.

Comment: I can figure out why Git can 'know' file removals, but how can it find out renamed files??  Thanks.

Comment: Git determines renamed files by analyzing the contents. It never actually tracks renames explicitly; it just assumes a file that is nearly identical to a previous file is a renamed version of it.

Comment: Yes, because @seanbun's answer is wrong, or at the very least subpar.